# Globally Available Azure App Architecture / Design?

Tags: azure, design-patterns

I am fairly new to Azure architecture and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an app that is currently available only in the Southeast Asia region; All my Azure Services (App Service, Azure SQL, etc.) are in the Southeast Asia region.

If I were to make the app available to other regions (ex. US or Europe), how do I scale my current Azure Setup? Because if it still points to the same region, there might be issues with latency/data location? Will I need to create Resource Groups for each region and perform replication?

I am trying to search for reference architectures by Microsoft but am having a hard time finding, or maybe I just don't know the correct terminology for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Azure Reference Architecture page, there's a section for Web applications:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/

and inside of it, a template for high availability web apps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region

In case Azure Front Door does not meet your requirements, take a look on Azure Traffic Manager.

Trafic Manager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/

LB with Azure Front Door
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-lb-with-azure-app-delivery-suite

Comment: Thanks but this seems more like for backups / high availability in case 1 region becomes unavailable? It seems to be different from improved latency / performance.

Comment: "Azure Front Door Service provides dynamic website acceleration (DSA) including global HTTP load balancing. It looks at incoming HTTP requests routes to the closest service backend / region for the specified hostname, URL path, and configured rules.
Front Door terminates HTTP requests at the edge of Microsoft’s network and actively probes to detect application or infrastructure health or latency changes. Front Door then always routes traffic to the fastest and available (healthy) backend. "